# how to make a variable accessible within my main function

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the long post, I have a very mediocre level with javascript, especially with Object-Oriented Programming.

In the past, I used javascript and jquery for rather simple tasks such as ticking a checkbox or submitting a form on a web page.

Today I would like to code a small flashcards game but I think this involves more complex programming structures which I did't master at this point.

Basically, this is what my game should do:

- when the user clicks on "play game" the game starts
- we fetch a list of words with ajax
- the words are then stored in the "loadedWords" array
- when the user clicks on "Next Word" we display the next word

Here is what I succeeded to do:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    const settings              = {};  
    const myGame                = new Game(settings);

    settings.playGameBtn        = document.querySelector('#playGame'); 

    switch(event.target) {

        case settings.playGameBtn:

            settings.gameDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
            settings.gameDiv.setAttribute("id", "gameDiv"); 
            document.body.appendChild(settings.gameDiv); 

            myGame.startGame(settings);

            break;

        default:

            break;

    }

}, false);


var Game = function(settings) {

    this.startGame=function (settings) {

        loadDoc( initializeWords );
     
    }

    function loadDoc( cFunction ) {

        var xhr;

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if ( this.readyState == 4 ) {

                cFunction(this);

            }

        };

        xhr.open("POST", "ajax.php", true);
        xhr.send(null);

    }

    function initializeWords(xhr) {

        var loadedWords = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        
        console.log(loadedWords); // the words are properly loaded here, in the array loadedWords"

        document.addEventListener('click',      mouseEventsListener);

        settings.wordDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
        settings.wordDiv.setAttribute("id", "word"); 
        settings.gameDiv.appendChild(settings.wordDiv); 

        settings.nextWordBtn = document.createElement('button'); 
        settings.nextWordBtn.setAttribute("id", "nextWordButton"); 
        settings.nextWordBtn.innerHTML = "Next Word";
        settings.gameDiv.appendChild(settings.nextWordBtn); 

    } 

    function mouseEventsListener (event){

        switch(event.target) {

            case settings.nextWordBtn:

                console.log(loadedWords); // ERROR! "Uncaught ReferenceError: loadedWords is not defined"

                displayNextWord(loadedWords);

                break;
     
            default:

                break;

        }

    }

    function displayNextWord(loadedWords) {

        settings.wordDiv.innerHTML          = loadedWords[0].word;

    } 

}
```

It turns out that when I click on "Next Word" the array "loadedWords" is empty in function mouseEventsListener (event)

How can I pass "loadedWords" and make it accessible within the main function "Game"?

Additionally, as I am very mediocre with javascript I am not sure the structure of my programming is properly coded, maybe you have suggestion especially regarding the imbrication of the different functions.

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: `loadedWords` is currently local to the `initializeWords` function. You could just define it **outside** of that function (at the same level as `this.startGame = ...`) to make it accessible within the whole `Game` function and all functions defined in it.

Comment: @subarachnid No, as `initializeWords` is an async callback. To get around this, the easiest would be to just move everything that uses `loadedWords` into the callback. If that isn't possible, then you'll have to look for Promises... Also, there doesn't seem to be necessary to use a constructor function here...

Comment: @FZs, It doesn't matter if it is async or not. The problem here is just the scope of the `loadedWords` variable. It is guaranteed that `mouseEventsListener` will only be called after the words have already been loaded so the function just needs access to that variable.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring this.loadedWords={} at the beginning of the function is a good solution.

Comment: It is set in an async callback, so it isn't possible.

Comment: Thank you everyone, yes subarachnid your solution works perfectly, thank you all once again.

I just added "this.loadedWords = {};" at the beginning of the Game function.

It works fine however it seems like i can not set properties to this object :

        this.loadedWords        = {};
        loadedWords.test        = "test"; // Uncaught ReferenceError: loadedWords is not defined
    at new Game

Comment: @LesDentsDeLaMer you have to explicitly use `this.` again there: `this.loadedWords.test = "test"`. JavaScript is not Java ;) However you don't have to add it to `this` at all. It should work just fine using `var` if you define it at the root level of your `Game` function.

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)